# TYPO3 extension custom repository = empty result

Tags: typo3, typo3-6.2.x, typo3-extensions

I'm working on Typo3 6.2, below is an extract from my controller :

```
    $event_to_display = $this->eventRepository->findByCustom();
    $this->view->assign('event', $event_to_display);
```

and this is my custom repository :

```
public function findByCustom()
{

    $query = $this->createQuery();
    $query->matching($query->equals('sys_language_uid', 0));
    return $query->execute();

}
```

but result is empty ! I believe my $query->equals() operation doesn't work but I can't understand why. Thus, I would like to add a second condition : how to do it ?

Edit : if I use findByUid() it works, then the issue must be located on my custom code, not the controller or the repo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think You forgot the set `StoragePid`. So, First check `storagePid` is set or not. If not set then set it first and clear the `Install Tool` cache and check gain.

**For set StoragePid.**

-: Go to the main page > Templates, then go to constant editor and set `StoragePID` of page with your records.

Answer (score 0):

`findByUid` will allways find your entity since it bypasses any other constraint.

Extbase repositories are based on the entities they're querying, which means they don't query the database directly, but rather the persistence manager for **properties** of your Entity. (This is not 100% accurate but it serves as a good picture)

To get entities from a different language (since your code queries the field), you should use the `QuerySettings` to modify the target language constraint:

```
$query->getQuerySettings()->setRespectStoragePage(false);
```

Comment: Hello Cedric, thanks for your answer. Same result with this method.. I just wanna stray in the current Entity scope and get the one with a specific pid and a specific langage id. It sounds simple but not for me ^^ How to ?